# iPhone security and Android MTP support

Tags: photos, mtp, ios

I'm trying to import photos from my iPhone to my Nexus 10 device (Android 5.1.1) using USB-OTG. The iPhone connects as a MTP device and will initially connect as a empty device until I press "Trust this device" on the dialog that appears on the iPhone as soon as I connect it. After pressing that button the phone will give access the photos.

The problem here is that the Camera Importer tool on the Nexus 10 scans for images as soon as I connect the phone, and because the iPhone connects as a empty device  won't find anything. As I press the "Trust this device" button on the iPhone the Camera Importer tool doesn't rescan the device for the now accessable photos, and I can't find a way to force a rescan manually. The only way for it to rescan is to reboot the tablet or reconnect the phone, but that also resets the "Trust" cycle on the iPhone, therefore making it show a empty device again.

I checked with Apple and there is no way to turn off this device trust feature on the iPhone (at least not without jailbreaking)
Is there any way the Camera Importer tool can re-scan a MTP device while its connected? (Official documentation is a non-help on this one)
If not, is there another good photo importer tool with MTP support?

Comment: What is this Camera Importer tool? Is this a separate app? Is it available in Play Store? If yes, consider sharing its link. If no, consider providing its AndroidManifest.xml. I do not precisely know what this tool is, I see that some third party media importer are also available. Perhaps try them to trigger the scan?

Comment: @Firelord The Camera Importer tool is included with the default set of Android apps (I think it's part of the Gallery app in Android 4.3 and below and part of the Photos app in Android 4.4 and up).